# UNC name resolution issue

Tags: unc

Have a win 2008 r2. after installing some patches the xp client machine can no longer access the file share. Win 7 machine was okay.

\\servername\    path **not** found
\\x.x.x.x\    path **not** found
\\servername.contoso.com\    path found 
 
ping servername    okay 
ping x.x.x.x    okay 
ping servername.contoso.com    okay 
netbios over tcp/ip is enabled 
TCP/IP Helper Service is enabled 
dcdiag & repadmin /replsum    okay

The DC is a PDC, RID, Infra master.

just no idea what when wrong after the server OS patching ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/3161949

NETBIOS communication outside of the local subnet is hardened. Therefore, by default, some features that depend on NETBIOS (such as SMB over NETBIOS) will not work outside the local subnet.

SUBKEY: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters
Value Name: AllowNBToInternet
Type: Dword
Value: 1

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\DependOnService`
from `SamSS Srv2` to `SamSS Srv`
and reboot your server.

Comment: the server in questions is already on SamSS Srv but still not working. Thanks